# Not able to load Snowflake external table from Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-s3, external, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am not able to load external table in snowflake from Amazon S3 bucket. External table is created successfully but while running the select command , nothing is returned. 
Weird thing is that COPY into command is working for the same table in snowflake.

Thanks,
Naveed

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. I am sure someone will be more likely to be able to help you if you share your code with them. Please read [ask] and the information on produce a [mre]

Answer (score 1):

```
You can run below commands to load the external table or add/remove files.

ALTER EXTERNAL TABLE [ IF EXISTS ] <name> REFRESH [ '<relative-path>' ]

ALTER EXTERNAL TABLE [ IF EXISTS ] <name> ADD FILES ( '<path>/[<filename>]' [ , [ '<path>/[<filename>'] ] )

ALTER EXTERNAL TABLE [ IF EXISTS ] <name> REMOVE FILES ( '<path>/[<filename>]' [ , [ '<path>/[<filename>]' ] )
```